# Why does bytearray() return a value greater than one byte?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, hex

I am trying to convert hex input into a bytearray.
Basically, I have tried:

1. `bytearray.fromhex('e832')`
2. converting to ints: `bytearray([232, 50])` which return the following:

   `bytearray(b'\xe82')`

instead of what I expected (and need output to look like):

```
bytearray(b'\xe8\x32')
```

Why is this? Isn't `xe82` greater than max for one byte?

using `bytes()` does the same thing.

(Python 3.8.1)

Comment: Python only uses `\x`escapes for characters which aren't printable ASCII. The hexadecimal `32` is equivalent to decimal `50`, which corresponds to the ASCII character "2". So the output is correct and exactly as expected.

Comment: ahh, I see. Is there any way to make bytearray output only hex values that you know of, just for better readability?

Comment: No, that's just how `repr` works. If you want to see the decimal values of each byte, you can do `list(b'\xe82')` => `[232, 50]`. Or if you're using Python >= 3.5, you can do `b'\xe82'.hex(' ')` => `'e8 32'`.

Comment: IOW: `b'\x32' == b'2'`